# Problem while connecting my app to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, sha1

My App name is AppBase
It is requesting for SHA-1 Hash key. I saw that people are opening **gradle>"application name">android** on the right side of the android studio for this but my application is not showing. What I have done wrong??

[image]

Comment: Can you try with **Refresh Gradle Project** on **AppBase**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gradle -> app -> android -> signingReport
```

[image: Check this image]